# Как получить XML используя SOAP?

Tags: php, soap

Имеется такой вот код:

```
$wsdl_url = "https://xxxxx?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url);
$params = new stdClass();
$params->login = "xxxx";
$params->token = "xxxx";
$cat = $client->GetData($params);
```

На выходе получаем массив данных.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить на выходе не массив, а XML-файл?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Сам себе и отвечу:

```
var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
```

Знатный велосипед, однако :D

Хехе! Как отвечать - так никого, а как минусы ставить - все д'Артаньяны :)